# Setting System properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

Please help in understanding on how i can setup the system properties on the Tomcat server v9. So whenever i need the property value i can access them using System.getProperty("home") in my java code.  I am using Eclipse

I tried setting JAVA_OPTS in catelina.bat but getting null in code.

this is my catelina.bat :

```
  rem Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%$JAVA_OPTS% -Dhome=\Users\Ayush\Documents\apache-tomcat-9.0.7"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% --add-modules java.se.ee"
```

i need to use home property in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use the batch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Servers tab, double click on tomcat server -> click on open launch configuration -> click on (x)=Arguments

In VMarguments add the following:

`-Dhome="\Users\Ayush\Documents\apache-tomcat-9.0.7"`